# Cryptographic failure while signing assembly 'The key container name '...' does not exist

Tags: visual-studio-2010

VS2010 professional, I am trying to compile a project that I downloaded I am getting this error:

```
Error   2   Cryptographic failure while signing assembly 
'E:\...\bsn.GoldParser.dll' -- 
'The key container name 'bsn' does not exist'
```

I don't care if it is signed or not. "Sign the assembly" is off in the project options and I have checked the .csproj file and SignAssembly is false. How do I get rid of this message?

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the line `<KeyContainerName>bsn</KeyContainerName>` from both `bsn.GoldParser.Test.csproj` and `bsn.GoldParser.csproj` by unloading the project and editing the project file
2. remove the PublicKey part from the attribute in `bsn.GoldParser\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` so it looks like this: `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("bsn.GoldParser.Test")]`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your AssemblyInfo.cs file to ensure that you don't have an AssemblyKeyName attribute specified ?